Delete certain text between commas in Excel
I need to delete all the emails that end with @live.com and keep the other emails in the cell.
Most cells contain multiple emails separated by commas. See below:
Example 1
Emails:
hello@gmail.com, hi-c@live.com, dv-ss@live.com, sadeq@live.com

Expected Output:
hello@gmail.com

Example 2
Emails:
hello@gmail.com, noha@main.com,hi-c@live.com, dv-ss@live.com, sadeq@live.com

Expected Output:
hello@gmail.com, noha@main.com

I'm beginner in Excel and I'm not sure how to use the functions here.
Thanks.

The following formula works with MS365 Version of Excel, since as per tagged post the formula will not be applicable for your version of Excel hence suggested to use Power Query which can elegantly split and then join the string into using a delimiter as well.

• Formula used in cell B1
=LET(
     a, TEXTSPLIT(A1,", "),
     TEXTJOIN(", ",1,FILTER(a, ISERR(SEARCH("@live.com",a)))))


Or, can be spilled as follows:
=MAP(A1:A3, LAMBDA(x,
 LET(b, TEXTSPLIT(x,", "),
 TEXTJOIN(", ",1,FILTER(b, ISERR(SEARCH("@live.com",b)))))))


This can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ onwards and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)


To use Power Query follow the steps:

First convert the source ranges into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as Table1



Next, open a blank query from Data Tab --> Get & Transform Data --> Get Data --> From Other Sources --> Blank Query



The above lets the Power Query window opens, now from Home Tab --> Advanced Editor --> And paste the following M-Code by removing whatever you see, and press Done


    let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Result", each Text.Combine(List.Select(Text.Split([Emails], ","), each not List.AnyTrue(List.Transform({"@live.com", "@yahoo.com"}, (x) => Text.EndsWith(Text.Lower(Text.Trim(_)), x)))), ", ")),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Result"})
in
    #"Removed Other Columns"



Lastly, to import it back to Excel --> Click on Close & Load or Close & Load To --> The first one which clicked shall create a New Sheet with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.


• For additional emails could try:
=LET(a, TEXTSPLIT(A1,","), 
 TEXTJOIN(", ",1,FILTER(a,BYCOL(ISERR(SEARCH({"@live.com";"@yahoo.com"},a)),
 LAMBDA(b,AND(b))))))



It worked amazingly!! Thank you very much Mayukh, you saved me a lot of time. I have a question what if wanted to add another email to be deleted should I add it after "@live.com" with an & or in the same quotation mark? Thanks.

Also is it case sensitive? Some emails were with capital letters and they weren't removed. Thanks.

In Formula change FIND() to SEARCH() while in Power Query code add Text.Lower() in front of the Text.Trim()

Can you please show me the syntax in the power Query code? I got confused.

It is updated in the answer. Please refer.

Many thanks for your prompt support.

You can also easily achieve your goal with the UDF function written in VBA.
The content of the function should be placed in a standard module inserted in the VBA editor. If you haven't used VBA, there's a lot of information on the web about it.
Then you call your function on the worksheet like a regular function. The first argument is the text to be processed, the second is the fragment to be omitted.
Use separators as you normally use in Excel.
Function FRemove(text As String, remv As String) As String
    Dim a As Variant
    a = Split(text, ",")
    a = Filter(a, remv, False)
    a = Join(a, ", ")
    FRemove = Application.Trim(a)
End Function



Hello MGonet. No this is my first time learning about VBA but I'll look more through it. Appreciate your help. Thanks.
